# Why do American speakers pronounce "the" as "/ðə/" before vowels?

Tags: pronunciation, articles, phonology, phonetics

I learned that we have to pronounce /ðə/ before consonants & /ði/ before vowels.

For example, the /ðə/ car, but the /ði/ earth.

But it seems that a lot of American people pronounce the /ðə/ before vowels, for example the /ðə/ era.

**Are these native speakers pronouncing wrong? or it is a dialect or something?**

Comment: If your teachers had taught you to pronounce *the* always as /ðə/, you would be asking "why do a lot of native English speakers sometimes pronounce it /ði/?"

Comment: @PeterShor I was told (non-native) that /ði/ is used for emphasis. Teachers (and I too now that I notice it) told me that only using /ði/ seems like you're emphasising everything weirdly.

Comment: @JJJ The long version  /ˈðiː/ is the emphatic one, but /ði/ is still considered standard before any vowel. Those are not the same thing because the emphatic one is stressed so that it is held longer and never reduced. There is only a length distinction between archaic *I shall give thee animals* and *I shall give the animals* — but the vowel is the same in both.

Comment: As a native speaker, I think the /ði/ pronunciation is only before low vowels. Or perhaps just vowels other than /i/. I would say /ðə/ before a high vowel like in "the eatery".

Comment: *By definition*, can `native speakers` *wrongly pronounce* their own language (even if some would consider their accent horrible)?  I'm dubious.

Comment: This has nothing to do with American English in particular.

Comment: The rules seem to be similar for 'a' versus 'an' preceding a vowel sound. What I've found interesting is that many American English speakers pronounce 'h' as a consonant and apply the a/an rule appropriately (a historic event), whereas most other English speakers soften the 'h' sound to the point of inaudibility and ignore it (an historic event). I say 'many AE speakers' because American English treatment of 'h' for the a/an rule seems to converging towards saying 'an historic event' even though the 'h' is still pronounced.

Comment: @rich “a history book” but “an historic event,” because the emphasis is on the second syllable in historic.

Comment: @RichMoss AmE is certainly not converging to *an historic event* ... if anything, it's going the other way [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+historic+event%2Ca+historic+event&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=5&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Can%20historic%20event%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20historic%20event%3B%2Cc0). And in my experience, Americans usually say either *a historic event* or *an 'istoric event* (although maybe I'm not listening closely enough).

Comment: @Xanne - I'd never noticed that pattern before. It does make sense that the emphasized first syllable would make the consonant word-separator (or the unseemly glottal stop) unnecessary. However I've been unable to find a codified rule to support it.

Comment: @PeterShor I've been hearing 'an historic' with the 'h' softened but pronounced in American news recently. [Apparently they're both correct, but 'a historic' is preferred](https://writingexplained.org/a-vs-an-difference)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Many speakers of Gen Am and also speakers of British Englishes, including some young RP speakers, use a *hard attack* on the second word  to separate a word-final and word initial vowel. For a minority of speakers this also occurs after the definite article. A ʜᴀʀᴅ  ᴀᴛᴛᴀᴄᴋ is when a speaker uses a glottal stop, [ ʔ ], at the beginning of a word starting with a vowel*. So, for example, instead of saying [ɛnd] for the word *end*, a speaker using a hard attack would say [ʔɛnd]. In this syllable initial position, the glottal stop will not be recognised as a /t/.

Speakers who use a hard attack to separate the vowel in *the* from a following vowel will therefore say:

- [ðə ʔɜ:θ] for *the earth*.

This is a relatively new phenomenon, at least in RP.  Will pedants decry any new and novel development in the language? Of course they will!

But are these speakers making mistakes? No! The rules of language are the rules which describe what real speakers of the language do. The Original Poster has therefore observed a real rule underlying such speakers' speech.

<sup>* [Note that this is a *hard* attack, not a *heart* attack](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/blog0605.htm)!</sup>

Comment: It seems to me that Americans have been using glottal stops to separate adjacent vowels for a lot longer than speakers of RP (who reputedly put an /r/ between two adjacent vowels that don't have a glide separating them already). So it's not surprising that Americans do this. But I'm surprised that RP speakers are starting to do this ... is the intrusive /r/ disappearing from RP?

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, RP speakers usually use intrusive /r/ before non-high vowels-- though never in this environment after the definite article (to the best of my knowledge). Speakers who use hard attack in this particular environment are still quite a minority. Re intrusive  /r/ I'm not aware of any observed trend, but in any case, intrusive /r/ is a possibility, not a necessity (and used to be frowned on by pedants). So in this respect intrusive /r/ different from syllable final orthographic /r/. One would assume that, as you conjecture, ...

Comment: @PeterShor ... if even a few speakers are using hard attack instead of intrusive /r/, it must be declining at least to some small degree. But I don't know.

Comment: I often hear what I think of as a "half-hearted glottal stop" after the schwa when Americans say things like *Do you want something **to eat?*** My ***BrE*** version interposes a ***/w/***, so in rapid speech the schwa practically disappears and I end up saying *...something **tweet***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Standard English will often use a stop instead of a linking glide between duplicate adjacent vowels, such as for *“the eel”* [ðiˈʔiːɫ] instead of the version with a linking glide [ðiʲˈiːɫ]. (Hmm, I’m unsure how best to show reduction in the unstressed /i/ there. I suppose you could write the reduced one as [ɨ] or [ɪ̈] or maybe even [ɪ], and then shorten or omit the length marker from the unreduced one. Slow, careful speech displays much less reduction than fast, connected speech, and may even introduce artificial pauses perceivable as your “half-hearted glottal stops”.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers there's also `tuh eat`.

Comment: "Will pedants decry any new and novel development in the language?" That's not pedantry. It's conservatism.

Comment: @Fumble The most common AmE variant of _something to eat_ would, I think, be [ˈsʌm(θ)ɪnəˈiːʔ(t)], with the /t/ in _to_ completely merged with the preceding nasal (/ŋt/ → [n]) and the [əˈiː] closer to being a diphthong than to having a glottal stop. The schwa may even be reduced to more or less nothing in rapid speech, making it essentially just _some(th)in’ eat_. The version you describe is not uncommon, but I would associate with deliberately clear speech more than with natural conversation.

Comment: @PeterShor the intrusive 'r' has never been used after the word "the". That would sound extremely strange. For example, "the Earth" would not be pronounced "the rEarth". Intrusive 'r' is only used in words that historically had an 'r', in words that are more than one syllable long and end in a schwa and words that end in a long vowel.

Comment: @tchrist I usually hear [ðiʲˈiːɫ] or [ðəˈʔiːɫ], but very rarely [ðiˈʔiːɫ]. Once you insert the glottal stop, the /i/ in "the" just feels unneeded.

Comment: @Araucaria good answer and I especially liked this "**The rules of language are the rules which describe what real speakers of the language do**"

Comment: @aesking , Thank you! That's my most important rule of linguistics.